# Set password for user, ignoring password policy

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, passwords

I'm trying to programmatically set the password of a specific user (local account, not domain), using `NetUserSetInfo`.  However in some cases it is giving me error 2245 (`NERR_PasswordTooShort`) or other policy-related errors.

In this specific case I want the program (running with admin permissions) to be able to set the password even if it is violation of the normal desktop password policy (it's a special account).  How do I get Windows to ignore the policy for this one operation?

Comment: Set the password policy of that user to a less restrictive policy.

Comment: I believe you'll have to change the policy, set the password, then restore the original policy.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do either of those things?